# How to deserialize Avro kafka stream in sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro, sparklyr

I am working with an avro format kafka database which I want to stream in to spark for data analysis using sparklyr for use in shiny web apps.

Using sparklyr I can connect a spark structured stream to the kafka db but I can't work out how to deserialize the avro. We use schema registry for schema management. Also I cannot work out how to always start reading the db from the beginning.

```r
library(sparklyr)

config <- spark_config()
config$sparklyr.shell.packages <-
  "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.0"

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", config = config)

read_options <- list(
  kafka.bootstrap.servers = "kafka:9092",
  subscribe = "testopic",
  key.serializer = "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer",
  value.serializer = "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer",
  schema.registry.url = "http://kafka:8081"
)

stream <-
  stream_read_kafka(sc, options = read_options) %>% stream_write_memory('kafka_1')
```

session info:

```
> devtools::session_info()
- Session info --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
 os       Windows >= 8 x64            
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_Australia.1252      
 ctype    English_Australia.1252      
 tz       Australia/Sydney            
 date     2019-03-26                  

- Packages ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package     * version date       lib source        
 askpass       1.1     2019-01-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 backports     1.1.3   2018-12-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 base64enc     0.1-3   2015-07-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 callr         3.2.0   2019-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 cli           1.1.0   2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 config        0.3     2018-03-27 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 DBI         * 1.0.0   2018-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 dbplyr        1.3.0   2019-01-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 devtools      2.0.1   2018-10-26 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 digest        0.6.18  2018-10-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 dplyr         0.8.0.1 2019-02-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 ellipsis      0.1.0   2019-02-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 forge         0.2.0   2019-02-26 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 fs            1.2.7   2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 generics      0.0.2   2018-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 glue          1.3.1   2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 htmltools     0.3.6   2017-04-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 htmlwidgets   1.3     2018-09-30 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 httr          1.4.0   2018-12-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 jsonlite      1.6     2018-12-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 openssl       1.3     2019-03-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 pillar        1.3.1   2018-12-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 pkgbuild      1.0.3   2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 pkgconfig     2.0.2   2018-08-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 pkgload       1.0.2   2018-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 prettyunits   1.0.2   2015-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 processx      3.3.0   2019-03-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 ps            1.3.0   2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 purrr         0.3.2   2019-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 r2d3          0.2.3   2018-12-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 R6            2.4.0   2019-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 rappdirs      0.3.1   2016-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 Rcpp          1.0.1   2019-03-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 remotes       2.0.2   2018-10-30 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 rlang         0.3.2   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 rprojroot     1.3-2   2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 rstudioapi    0.10    2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 sparklyr    * 1.0.0   2019-02-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 tibble        2.1.1   2019-03-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 tidyselect    0.2.5   2018-10-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 usethis       1.4.0   2018-08-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 withr         2.1.2   2018-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 yaml          2.2.0   2018-07-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)

[1] C:/Users/robin/Documents/R/win-library/3.5
[2] C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.3/library
```